# How to override get_queryset() of ModelAdmin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I want to override a ModelAdmin to limit some users.
The superadmins have all the rights but the others have restricted rights. They can't see/add/modify/delete all objects but only some.
Also, the objects they can modify contain a many_to_many field and I want to limit the choices in the list.

For this, I overloaded several methods, but I have a problem when I overload get_queryset().
Indeed, it reduces the list of objects, which is perfect in my case but when I click on an object to modify it, I have the following error:

```
MultipleObjectsReturned at /fr/admin/commission/article/26/change/

get() returned more than one Article -- it returned 2!

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/fr/admin/commission/article/26/change/?_changelist_filters=q%3D
Django Version:     2.2.24
Exception Type:     MultipleObjectsReturned
Exception Value:    

get() returned more than one Article -- it returned 2!

Exception Location:     /home/aurelien/dev/extranet_thourotte/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py in get, line 410
Python Executable:  /home/aurelien/dev/extranet_thourotte/venv/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.9.5
```

my ModelAdmin:

```py
@admin.register(Article)
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    """
    ArticleAdmin to save automaticaly the author
    """
    list_display = ('titre', 'auteur', 'date', 'date_update')
    list_filter = ('rubriques', 'auteur',)
    search_fields = ('titre',)
    exclude = ('auteur',)
    
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            rubriques = Rubrique.objects.filter(admins=request.user)
            queryset = queryset.filter(rubriques__in=rubriques)
        return queryset

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_superuser and db_field.name == "rubriques":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Rubrique.objects.filter(admins=request.user)
        return super(ArticleAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)

    def get_changeform_initial_data(self, request):
        if OptionsExtranet.objects.exists():
            return {'date_fin': OptionsExtranet.objects.first().end_date,
                    'date_debut': datetime.now()}

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.auteur = request.user
        obj.save()

    def get_object(self, request, object_id, extra_context):
        obj = super(ArticleAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)
        setattr(obj, "send_mail", False)
        return obj

    def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
        return redirect("detail_article", pk=obj.pk)

    def response_change(self, request, obj):
        return redirect("detail_article", pk=obj.pk)
     
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        rubriques = Rubrique.objects.all()
        rubriques_admins = []
        for rubrique in rubriques:
            for admin in rubrique.admins.all():
                rubriques_admins.append(admin)
        if request.user in rubriques_admins:
            return True
        return False

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        rubriques = Rubrique.objects.all()
        rubriques_admins = []
        for rubrique in rubriques:
            for admin in rubrique.admins.all():
                rubriques_admins.append(admin)
        if request.user in rubriques_admins:
            return True
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return True
        rubriques = Rubrique.objects.all()
        rubriques_admins = []
        for rubrique in rubriques:
            for admin in rubrique.admins.all():
                rubriques_admins.append(admin)
        if request.user in rubriques_admins:
            return True
        return False

    class Media:
        js = ('admin/js/commission.js',)
```

I have this error because my user (not admin) is in 2 different "Rubrique". In the query set I get 2 results.

```py
rubriques = Rubrique.objects.filter(admins=request.user)   # 2 objets returned !
queryset = queryset.filter(rubriques__in=rubriques)
```

---

### EDIT

I understood the problem.

In fact it doesn't work when on an existing object that I want to modify, the many_to_many field contains more objects that my user has the right to.
So I can't only display a reduced list. So I have to find another solution. Maybe I can override the data validation?

In fact I have the error as soon as several "Sections" are selected.

My models:

```py
class Rubrique(models.Model):
    """
    Rubrique Model
    """
    name = models.CharField('nom', max_length=255)
    utilisateurs = models.ManyToManyField(User, verbose_name="Utilisateurs")
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User,
                                    related_name="rubrique_admins",
                                    verbose_name="Administrateurs de la commission (peut modifier les notes)")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Commission"
        verbose_name_plural = "Commissions"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Article(models.Model):
    """
    Article model
    """
    titre = models.CharField('titre', max_length=255)
    
    contenu = HTMLField("contenu")
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="article_auteur", verbose_name="auteur",
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField("date de création", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    date_update = models.DateTimeField("date de dernière mise à jour", auto_now=True,
                                       auto_now_add=False)
    date_debut = models.DateField("date de début de parution", auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    date_fin = models.DateField("date de fin de parution",
                                auto_now=False,
                                auto_now_add=False)
    lien = models.URLField("lien", max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    files = models.ManyToManyField("commission.FileUpload", verbose_name="Fichiers",
                                   related_name="fichier_article",
                                   blank=True)
    rubriques = models.ManyToManyField("commission.Rubrique",
                                       related_name="articles",
                                       verbose_name="rubriques",
                                       blank=True)
```

Comment: Is there a one to many or many to many relationship between `Rubrique` and `Article`? It would be useful if you showed their models with at least the relationship to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple `Rubrique` objects for a given `Article` object. Hence when you write `queryset.filter(rubriques__in=rubriques)` the ORM needs to make a *join*, this join causes rows to be duplicated and hence `get` may return duplicate data giving you an error.

You can use [`distinct` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to remove the duplicates:

```
def get_queryset(self, request):
    queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        rubriques = Rubrique.objects.filter(admins=request.user)
        queryset = queryset.filter(rubriques__in=rubriques).distinct()
    return queryset
```